# vue insert a component twice in same page shows same content

Tags: vue.js

I've a card component (*tshirt*) insert twice on the same page, i would like to show different content but it updates the first one having the same content as the second one.

```
<div>
   <tshirt:key="user_h" :tshirt="{svg:svgH}"></tshirt>
   <tshirt:key="user_a" :tshirt="{svg:svgA}"></tshirt>
</div>
```

then in method:

```
 // step 1
teamRepository.getTshirt(1,1,false).then(r=>{
   this.svgH= r.data.svg;
   console.log(this.svgH)
 });

// step 2
teamRepository.getTshirt(2,2,false).then(r=>{
    this.svgA= r.data.svg;
    console.log(this.svgA)
 });
```

The Axios getTshirt returns the API content: I notice in console log the last promise is returned before the first one (?)

During runtime I have svgH=H the (at step2) svgA = A and svH=svgA=A!  Why??

Comment: Log r.data please and update the question with the logged values.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? It is hard to tell what exactly is happening; there could be multiple causes for this. E.g. the relevant parts of your components - or the whole components if you are unsure.

Comment: @sandrooco the log looks ok: both r are different but the second one is returned before the first one!

Comment: @Roy sure fixed the typo. Not the issue.

Comment: There's no colon after a `return`.

Comment: Fixed! The issue was in SVG returned in r: it has a style inside the code which was overwriting the code of the first SVG. Vue code was perfect. Thanks for helping me.